# UDP error on beginPacket

Tags: c, arduino

I got an error on my arduino when I send a UDP-package any ip.
There 2 problems when I try to send a packet to `_targetIp`:

1. When called from `loop()` then `udpSender.endPacket()` freeze forever (on second call, first call was fine)
2. When called from `setup()` then `udpSender.beginPacket(...)` returns 0

Code:

```
IPAddress _targetIp(192, 168, 59, 250);
int _sendPort = 4321;
EthernetUDP _udpSender;  

(...)

void sendUpd(int pinIndex, int value)
{
    // if I wrote something like this: 
    // udpSender.beginPacket(_udpSender.remoteIP(), _sendPort)
    // then is all fine
    if (_udpSender.beginPacket(_targetIp, _sendPort) != 1)
    {
      Serial.println("socket error!");
      return;
    }

    _udpSender.write(pinIndex);
    _udpSender.write("=");
    _udpSender.write(value);

    int sendState = _udpSender.endPacket(); // hang forever when called from "loop()"
    if ( sendState != 1 )
    {
      // enters with 0 as "sendState" when called from "setup()"
      Serial.print("send error: ");
      Serial.println( sendState );
    }    
}
```

Can anybody explain that for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Founded solutions:

1. Not the call `_updSender.endPacket()` freezes. The code to read a specific digital in (`digitalRead(52)`) causes the strange reaction.
2. I dont know how, but the arduino check if the host alive. If the host not reachable, the `_udpSender.endPacket()` returns 0.

Explantation:
Resolving the IP to an MAC adress fails. So the error does not came from UDP (layer 4 OSI). The error happend in data-link-layer (=2) and explains point 2.